# Como utilizar várias promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

Não tenho muita experiencia com node.js, e precisava de gerar vários links assinados, tenho este bloco de código que funciona bem.

```
bucket.file("test_users/xxxxx/avatar/thumbnail.jpeg")
        .getSignedUrl(options)
        .then(results => {
            const url = results[0];
            res.send(url);
            return true
        }).catch( err => {
            console.log("error generating signed url", err);
            return false
        })
```

Tendo uma lista com os diversos ids de utilizador, como posso fazer para criar uma lista de links?

Comment: Como seriam essas "diversas" promises? Elas variam de acordo com o "xxxx" na URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), que resolve uma lista de promessas simultaneamente. Desse modo, uma promessa final será retornada assim que todas aquelas passadas forem resolvidas.

Um exemplo:

```js
// Nossa função que retorna uma promessa:
function getUserName(username) {
  return fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => data.name);
}

// Lista de usuários:
const users = ['gaearon', 'sindresorhus', 'tj', 'mdo'];

// Criamos uma lista de promessas a partir da nossa
// lista de usuários. Note que todas elas chamam a
// função `getUserName`, que retorna uma promessa.
const promises = users.map((username) => getUserName(username));

// Executamos todas as promessas:
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((list) => console.log(list))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Como você pode ter visto, utilizamos o [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) como forma de mapear um array de valores (uma lista de nome de usuários) em uma lista de promessas, que serão todas resolvidas pelo `Promise.all`.

Então, os dois códigos a seguir são equivalentes:

```js
Promise.all(
  ['gaearon', 'sindresorhus', 'tj', 'mdo']
    .map((username) => getUserName(username))
)
  .then(/* ... */)
  .catch(/* ... */);
```

```
Promise.all([
  getUserName('gaearon'),
  getUserName('sindresorhus'),
  getUserName('tj'),
  getUserName('mdo')
])
  .then(/* ... */)
  .catch(/* ... */);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta pormenorizada!! Era mesmo o que eu precisava